# Send user online/offline status to Laravel with socket.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, laravel-5, socket.io, disconnect

I have a chat app as real-time with socket.io. I want to save online/offline status on the database in Laravel back-end. For online status I don't have problem, but for offline status, I don't have any plan. My front-end framework is Angularjs 1.x and use JWT for authentication.

As matter of fact I want to save offline user status in database when user close browser of change route and `emit` all users from these user's status?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be just reacting to the socket.io server side events like the listening the socket connection and disconnect events.

This would the easiest solution, the problems would occur when your server crashes and you never receive the disconnect event. To avoid such problem, you could create interval check, which after every minute checks the opened sockets and users opened/closed in DB and updates if there changes.

Client side:

```
var socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:3000/", { query: "id=434354fds43" });
```

Server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(80);
var users = {};

io.use(function (socket, next) {
    console.log('Query: ', socket.handshake.query);
    var id = socket.handshake.query.id;
    if (id) {
        users[socket.id] = id;
        return next();
    }
    // call next() with an Error if you need to reject the connection.
    next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // New connection, get the ID from map
    var id = socket.id;

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        // User left
        delete users[id];
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to pass username to disconnect event in `socket.server.js`. how to pass parameter from client.js

Comment: Added example how to pass data from client to server, example with user id.